# Trouble with undefined symbols in Rust's ffi when using a C/Fortran library

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, ffi

I have a library, namely [pfapack](https://michaelwimmer.org/downloads.html) (1), that I want to use in rust. So the initial code is written in Fortran, but a C interface exists and works well. I want to make a Rust crate (2) that ships this code so I can use it in any other Rust project (3). Doing so, (3) gives an undefined symbol error.

I have written a build script in (2) that calls (1)'s build method. I then use `cc` to combine the object files and link the needed libraries. I then used `bindgen` to generate bindings for the functions I need. I would expect that (3) would be able to see the object that were compiled at (2) build time, but it can't.
The exact step taken are:

- New crate with (1)'s source code.
- (2) build.rs

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
// This makefile call a custom root makefile that only calls the two
// makefiles in c_interface/ and fortran/
    Command::new("make").output() 
        .expect("Failed to make");

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=c_interface");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=fortran");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=pfapack");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=cpfapack");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=gfortran");

}
```

- (3) build.rs

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=lapack");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=blas");
}
```

Original example compilation to use pfapack

```
gcc -O3 -I c_interface/ foo.c -o foo.out c_interface/libcpfapack.a fortran/libpfapack.a -lm -lblas -llapack -lgfortran
```

The command used to generate bindings came from https://github.com/blas-lapack-rs/lapack-sys/blob/master/bin/generate.sh as it uses the same naming convention:
generate.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eux

bindgen --allowlist-function='^.*_$' --use-core pfapack.h \
  | sed -e 's/::std::os::raw:://g' \
  | sed -e '/__darwin_size_t/d' \
  > pfapack.rs

rustfmt pfapack.rs
```

Compiling (3) gives this error https://pastebin.com/4FubsYx9
Ignoring a big blob of flags, the error:

```
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/dumbo/Documents/test_pfapack/target/debug/deps/test_pfapack-d08bc25fe63b6ef8.ka29pyd46xgunxk.rcgu.o: in function `pfapack_sys::dskpfa':
          /home/dumbo/Documents/pfapack-sys/src/pfapack-bind.rs:249: undefined reference to `dskpfa'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 
  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)
 
error: could not compile `test_pfapack` due to previous error
```

(2) Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "pfapack-sys"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
links = "pfapack"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"

[dependencies.num-complex]
version = "0.4"
default-features = false

[lib]
name = "pfapack_sys"

[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0.79"
```

Comment: Please include the error from the compiler. Might be worth sharing the Cargo.toml as well. Does the Rust crate have anything relevant to reproduce this, or can it be left with an empty library?

Comment: Don't use `cc::Build...object` to include a static library in your build. Instead use the appropriate `cargo:rustc-link-lib` entries, e.g. `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=pfapack"); println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/path/to/the/library);`

Comment: @Jmb I did this when I tried to debug myself, but pfapack is not precompiled when I import the crate. Would it be better to have pfapack precompiled and just link it? What I tried to do up until now was to just ship it vendored with the binary, but perhaps I missunderstand a lot of things.

Comment: Please inline the error directly into the question.

Comment: Static libraries must be linked with the binary project → you should add `pfapack` and `cpfapack` to the (3) `build.rs`, not the (2).

Comment: @Jmb I just posted an answer that feels a bit like a bodge but works for my case. Linking it to (2) did work, but I wonder how it would behave be had this *-sys crate been a crate from crate.io and not from my local disk. Can this break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple and right under my nose. Note that the symbol not found does not have an ending underscore, as `pfapack` functions do after mangling. This was because I tried to do the bindings to the C interface and the pretty Rust functions in the same crate. Looking at the Rust book, https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#-sys-packages, the convention is to have a `*-sys` crate that just does the binding, and have another crate named `*` that does the pretty functions. Thus, I needed to update the build script.
Here is the updated (2) build.rs

```
// build script
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    Command::new("make").output()
        .expect("Failed to make");

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=c_interface");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=fortran");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=pfapack");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=cpfapack");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=gfortran");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=lapack");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=blas");
}
```

I renamed this package `pfapack-sys`. Created a new crate named `pfapack`(4) that depends on `pfapack-sys`. Now, update `Cargo.toml`(3) to depend on (4). Now works out of the box.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the build script modifies the source directory, which is not the best. Is there a way to place all the object files in OUT_DIR?